# SSIS Foreach ADLS File Enumerator

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-lake

I have a work with `azure` etc,
I build a job in `ssis` that contains a for each for `ADLS (Azure data lake store)`, it produces the path for some files. i make a data flow task inside the for each and add a `ADLS Source` with an expression for `ADLS file path` is dynamic by a variable that my for each produce.

When I run it, it always produces an error :
[image: error image]
but when I write the variable that for each product to the file path it runs correctly (which is just 1 source, not all sources from for each)

Did anyone get an idea?

Answer (score 0):

ADLS source does not support files at root folder.
If such a file is enumerated as passed to ADLS source, you get the error.